# Autodesk Forge Translation Error - Extractor Code 1073741819

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am getting the below error back for a failed translation.

The error I received is: `Extractor error code -1073741819`

I was wondering if someone could point me to somewhere that documents what the error codes mean so we can address the issue with our upload.

```
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2ViYXBwLmNhZHNoYXJlLmNvLzE2MTQxNzMzMTgyOTMtRjEwMTQ3MCUyMC0lMjBSMjUwMC5qdA",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "name": "1234-filename.jt",
        "progress": "complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Extractor error code -1073741819",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "svf",
        "status": "failed"
    }
],
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"progress": "complete",
"type": "manifest",
"region": "US",
"version": "1.0",
"status": "failed"
```

}

Comment: can you please add your `POST job` parameters? this error mostly indicate something wrong with file or with the way the job was posted